# c++ vector generate function class object

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have to use 'generate' function on vector to create 10 objects. I have class Point with constructor:

```
Point(){
        this->x=rand()%100;
        this->y=rand()%100;
};
```

Then I create a vector and use 'generate' function:

```
vector<Point> v (10);
generate (v.begin(), v.end(), Point());
```

When I compile it I receive this error:

```
Type 'Point' does not provide a call operator
```

I don't know why.

Comment: std::generate expects a function object. Look up into that.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to fill the vector with default constructed instances of `Point`.

Before coming to your actual issue, that call to `std::generate` is unnecessary, as `v` will already have 10 default constructed instances of `Point`.

But if you really want to call it, [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) expects as `Generator` a function object, i.e. an object with `operator()`. `Point` doesn't have one, and the compiler complains. Passing a lambda is a good idea, as they are such function objects:

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), []() {
    return Point{};
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The prototype for the generator function is described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate). It must be a function that returns the next value to generate. You are passing a single default constructed instance of `Point`. Perhaps you were trying to provide `Point`'s constructor as the generator function, but a constructor does not meet the requirement (it doesn't return anything), should never be called directly, and it's address can never be obtained (neither can you get a reference to one).

You must provide a separate function that simply returns points. The easiest way is to pass `std::generate` a lambda function. You would do something like this :

```
std::vector<Point> v(10);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), []() { return Point{}; });
```

However, note that the line `std::vector<Point> v(10);` already creates 10 default constructed `Point` objects. Since your randomization logic is in your default constructor, it's redundant to use `std::generate` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you need a function that generates the Points

```
Point RandomPoint() { return Point(); }

int main(int argA, char** argV)
{
    vector<Point> v(10);

    generate(v.begin(), v.end(), RandomPoint);

    return  0;
}
```